# JS Regex for Capturing Last Set of Parenthesis (Excluding Nested)

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have found a few articles that talk about capturing what's inside a set of parenthesis, but can't seem to find one that specifically ignores nested parenthesis. Also, I would like to only capture the last set.

So in essence there are three rules:

1. Capture text INSIDE of parenthesis
2. Capture the content of only the LAST parenthesis
3. Capture the content inside ONLY ONE SET of parenthesis (do not touch nesting)

Here are the 3 examples:

- `Pokemon Blue Version (Gameboy Color)` should return `Gameboy Color`
- `Pokemon (International) (Gameboy Color)` should return `Gameboy Color`
- `Pokemon Go (iPhone (7))` Should return `iPhone (7)`

What would be the correct way of programming this in JS/jQuery (`.match()`, `.exec()`)?

Comment: You can try `/\((.*?)(?:\)|$)/g` regex, but this will not handle nested `()`

Comment: Features to handle nested brackets (or other) with regex don't exist in Javascript. In other words, you can't do it with a single pattern.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Could you point me to any pitfalls I may have made or forgotten in my answer?

Comment: @BramVanroy: you can see here: https://regex101.com/r/KzOt7W/2 (check eventual updates)

Comment: Very interesting... @CasimiretHippolyte, you said it can't be done with a single pattern - so do you have a multi-pattern alternative? I am open to use a more complicated approach. If not, I can give BramVanroy +1, althoough it is not perfect, it can most likely suit my needs for now

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Unbalanced cases come from incomplete data, but the second example is indeed justified. I'm afraid it can't be matched with a single JS Regex.

Comment: @Hybrid: the alternative approach is the classic one with a hand made parser and a stack you increment on opening brackets and decrement on closing brackets.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I will not even pretend that I understand what you are saying, lmao. I'm guessing you mean some sort of recursion script that will hunt for parenthesis - in either case, it would be overkill. Thank you for your help - if you would like to convert your comment into an answer (which says there is no viable answer), then I will surely give you the correct answer check.

Comment: @Hybrid : The algorithm is simple: you have a `flag` var and you loop over your string character by character, when the char is `(` => `flag++` , when the char is `)` => `flag--` and if after that `flag==0` this means that brackets are balanced (note that you also need to control that `flag` is never negative, to store the start index when `flag==0` and the char is `(`, to extract the possible candidate substring when char is `)` and flag is zero)

Comment: @Hybrid: see Chris Morgan answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122751/how-to-match-a-input-parenthesis-with-regular-expression-in-javascript/4122990#4122990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I described in comments, feel free to define the behaviour you want when parenthesis are not balanced (if needed):

```
function lastparens(str) {
    var count = 0;
    var start_index = false;
    var candidate = '';

    for (var i = 0, l = str.length; i < l; i++) {
        var char = str.charAt(i);

        if (char == "(") {
            if (count == 0) start_index = i;
            count++;
        } else if (char == ")") {
            count--;

            if (count == 0 && start_index !== false)
                candidate = str.substr (start_index, i+1);

            if (count < 0 || start_index === false) {
                count = 0;
                start_index = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return candidate;
}
```

test cases:

```
var arr = [ 'Pokemon Blue Version (Gameboy Color)',
            'Pokemon (International) (Gameboy Color)',
            'Pokemon Go (iPhone (7))',

            'Pokemon Go ( iPhon(e) (7) )',
            'Pokemon Go ( iPhone ((7)) )',
            'Pokemon Go (iPhone (7)' ];

arr.forEach(function (elt, ind) {
    console.log( elt + ' => ' + lastparens(elt) );
} );
```

[demo](https://eval.in/692002)

Comment: Ah, that's smart. Instead of building the string yourself, keeping track of the start index and then using substring. I am sure your solution will be faster than my edited-in one. At least for smaller strings. If you'd reverse the process and start from the back I think you can gain some performance.

Comment: Perfect! I added `candidate.slice(1,-1)` to strip the final parenthesis, but this worked amazingly. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Hybrid: yes, instead of slicing the string, change: `candidate = str.substr (start_index, i+1);` to `candidate = str.substr (start_index + 1, i);`, you can also try Bram Vanroy suggestions that can improve the code (searching from the end)

Comment: @BramVanroy: interesting suggestions. Not sure that this approach is faster since javascript is an interpreted language, but it will be probably the case with a compiled language.

Answer (score 3):

https://regex101.com/r/UOFxWC/2

```js
var strings = [
  'Pokemon Blue Version (Gameboy Color)',
  'Pokemon (International) (Gameboy Color)',
  'Pokemon Go (iPhone (7))'
];

strings.forEach(function(string) {
  var re = /\(([^)]+\)?)\)(?!.*\([^)]+\))/ig;
  var results = re.exec(string);
  console.log(results.pop());
});
```

Alternatively, you can parse the string yourself. The idea is to start from the back, each time you see `)` add one to `depth`, subtract one if you see `(`. When depth is `> 0`, prepend the current character to a temporary string. Because you only want the final group, we can bail out (`break`) as soon as we have a full match, i.e. the sub string exists, and depth is back to zero. Note that this will not work with broken data: when the groups are not balanced you'll get odd results. so you have to make sure your data is correct.

```js
var strings = [
  'Pokemon Blue Version (Gameboy Color)',
  'Pokemon (International) (Gameboy Color)',
  'Pokemon Go (iPhone (7))',
  'Pokemon Go (iPhon(e) (7))',
  'Pokemon Go ( iPhone ((7)) )'
];

strings.forEach(function(string) {
  var chars = string.split('');
  var tempString = '';
  var depth = 0;
  var char;
  while (char = chars.pop()) {
    if (char == '\(') {
      depth--;
    }
    if (depth > 0) {
      tempString = char + tempString;
    }
    if (char == '\)') {
      depth++;
    }

    if (tempString != '' && depth === 0) break;
  }
  console.log(tempString);
});
```

Comment: I haven't seen your new version, it's indeed a good algorithm. You don't need to escape parenthesis (escapes are currently ignored), and there's perhaps something to do to limit the number of tests. Whatever, starting from the end is a good idea.