# Match text in nested parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

As the title says, I cant figure out how to match text inside a nested parenthesis (only in nested parenthesis). E.g

I have this text `Hi my (name is (Jhon) and(i dont) know how (to)match) this`.
The text I need to match is `Jhon`, `i dont` and `to`.

But text like this one `hi i have (a parenthesis)` should not match anything

Every answer i've seen until now uses recursive regex but I can not use a recursive regex in js and also I dont need a dinamic nested level identifier, just the text (whatever text) is inside the second parenthesis. `((this text))`

I've tried (with no success) this `{({([^{}])*})*}`

This is not a dupe since The guy at the other question just ask for a single parenthesis....

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/By6pGx/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but that also matches `also matches (this text inside here)` and it shouldnt

Comment: So, you first want to parse the nested parentheses and then apply that regex, right? See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122751/how-to-match-a-input-parenthesis-with-regular-expression-in-javascript). Once you get the string parsed, use the regex from my comment (from another linked thread).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, i mean, i just want to match the text (if there is any) in the parenthesis that is inside a parenthesis (it doesn't go lower than that). But if there is only one parenthesis it shouldnt match it

Comment: You may certainly do that with a "single" parsing code, but it won't involve a regex. JS regexp does not support recursion. Once you come up with some code and get stuck, please  update the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So basically I can not do that using a regex? it is just match a parenthesis inside another parenthesis. I thought it was possible

Comment: Yes, it is possible in PHP, Ruby, .NET regex, but JS regex engine is different and does not support recursion, nor balanced constructs.

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/752guzj8/).